# Which is more acidic: p-xylene or 3-methoxytoluene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

> Which is more acidic: p-xylene or 3-methoxytoluene?

$\ce{OCH3}$ shows -I and +M effect, and $\ce{CH3}$ shows +I effect. Since, the former shows some -I effect, it should be more acidic. But that's not the case. Any other explanation here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{Acidic Strength}\propto \text{-I, -M, Negative Hyperconjugation effects} \propto \dfrac{1}{\text{+I, +M, +Hyperconjugation effect}}$

Recall that $\ce{-OCH3}$ is a **moderately activating group** as its mesomeric effect overrules its inductive electron withdrawing effect.

On the other hand, you must be aware that $\ce{-CH3}$ is only **weakly activating** because of hyper conjugation and inductive electron releasing effect.

Now, its easy to conclude that a strongly activating group would result in more electron density over and around the benzene ring and hence destabilise the anion formed after deprotonation. Thus, we'd expect *p*-methoxytoluene to be less acidic than *p*-xylene.